# How can I create the cycle of numbers?

Tags: r, vector

I am using R, and wonder if anyone can help me this.
I want to transform this vector:

```
y<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
```

to

```
y<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

So I can do the following:

```
v<-c(rep("a",4), rep("b",2), rep("c",3), rep("d",3)) 
paste (v, y, sep="")
[1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "b1" "b2" "c1" "c2" "c3" "d1" "d2" "d3"
```

Comment: What language? Also, have you come up with any psuedocode?

Comment: using a changed version the main loop of a `run length encoding` algorithm you can do that, but depends on the language

Comment: What is the logic behind this transformation?

Comment: Sorry for confusion due to my rough post. I edited it and look for feedbacks. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
    paste0(letters[x], unlist(tapply(x,x, seq_along)))
}
f1(y)
#  [1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "b1" "b2" "c1" "c2" "c3" "d1" "d2" "d3"


f2 <- function(x) {
    x <- letters[x]
    ll <- unique(x)
    make.unique(c(ll, x), sep="")[-seq_len(length(ll))]
}
f2(y)
#  [1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "b1" "b2" "c1" "c2" "c3" "d1" "d2" "d3"
```

Comment: @Chia-hung -- Certainly, as my updated answer will show you. I've also added a couple of other somewhat more robust options for you to consider.

Comment: +1 - also `function(x) paste0(letters[x], sequence(rle(x)$lengths))`

Comment: @flodel, there would be a little bit of a difference between, say, `ave` and `rle` for this purpose. For example, consider the following: `set.seed(1); z <- sample(y); paste0(letters[z], ave(z, z, FUN=seq_along)); paste0(letters[z], sequence(rle(z)$lengths))` (but it's not clear what the OP would want in such a situation).

Comment: I agree on the differences, but I don't think the OP is even considering that case: his example suggests pretty strong assumptions on the input, for which all current answers are valid.

Comment: @flodel, Just pointing the difference out :) I personally like the "`make.unique`" trick as I hadn't seen it used that way before.

Comment: @flodel -- Funny, that was actually my initial answer. Like Ananda, I came to see it as not robust enough, even though it does work with the OP's example, and I edited it out.

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised `ave` isn't here yet:

```
> paste0(letters[y], ave(y, y, FUN=seq_along))
 [1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "b1" "b2" "c1" "c2" "c3" "d1" "d2" "d3"
```

Comment: Yes, this is great. `ave()` has to be in the running for title of worst-named R function, though.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Well, there's always `joshave<-function(...) ave(...)` :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, who is "Jo" and why do they have to shave?