# expand vector based on another vector

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have these vectors:

```
g_number=c(3,2,4)
g_names=c("b", "c", "d")
```

I would like to create the following vector based on g_number and g_names:

```
vnames=c("b.1", "b.2", "b.3", "c.1", "c.2", "d.1", "d.2", "d.3", "d.4")
```

I tried:

```
rep(g_names, g_number)
```

but this those not generates exactly what I want

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with @akrun's suggestion, but you could also try something like:

```
make.unique(c(g_names, rep(g_names, g_number)))[-seq_along(g_names)]
# [1] "b.1" "b.2" "b.3" "c.1" "c.2" "d.1" "d.2" "d.3" "d.4"
```

The basic idea is to use `make.unique` on the result of `rep`. However, since `make.unique` would have the first value be bare (without a number), we add the "g_names" value to the vector created by `rep`, and then remove the bare values.

Comment: Nice. I was trying to figure out how to get `unique.names` to work here. Maybe you got it here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19396664/1191259

Answer (score 2):

We could try

```
 sprintf('%s.%d',rep(g_names, g_number),sequence(g_number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I could by doing:

```
 paste(rep(g_names, g_number), sequence(g_number), sep=".")
```

Comment: You get `c.2` then `d.3` with that, though. Try `paste(rep(g_names, g_number), sequence(g_number), sep=".")`.